# Magento2 How to remove coupon code programatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am using a custom script to apply multiple coupons at a time for example:

1. GET100OF
2. GET200OF
3. GET300OF

Now, If the user wants to remove GET200OF then how to do this?
Below solution does not works:

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode('')
                            ->collectTotals()
                            ->save();
```